# How do I select all messages sent between two users in their sent order?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How do I select all messages sent between two users in their sent order?
the scenery is this.

User A: Hello
User B: Hi, there.
User A: how are you?

Here is the code I use to select messages between two users.

```
    Tab    = #pms{from='$1',to='$2',_='_'},
    Guard  = [{'xor',{'=:=',['$1','$2'],[MyId,Recepient]},{'=:=',['$1','$2'],[Recepient,MyId]}}],
    Result = ['$_'],
    mnesia:select(pms,[{Tab,Guard,Result}])
```

The result is something like this:

A:Hello,
A:how are you
B:Hi, there.

the order of messages are messed up. 
table type o is ordered set

Answer (score 1):

You need to put timestamps in the table. `ordered_set` tables are ordered by term ordering. From http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html<sup>1</sup>

> The ordered_set works on the Erlang term order...

<sub>1. Mnesia is built on top of ETS/DETS, and as a result, inherits many of its features.</sub>

Comment: The op stated: *table type o is ordered set*

Comment: Thanks. I managed to miss that and in my haste to answer, missed the mark.